# Javascript property that is an Object not the same as object

Tags: javascript, object, conditional-statements, object-literal

I can't figure this out...

I have two simple objects defined:

```
 var adam = {
  name: "Adam",
  spouse: terah

}

var terah = {
  name: "Terah",
  age: 32,
  height: 66,
  weight: 125,
  hairColor: "brown",
  spouse: adam
}
```

The only property I'm concerned with is the spouse property. 
When I test:

```
console.log(terah.spouse.spouse);
> Object {name: "Terah", age: 32, height: 66, weight: 125, hairColor: "brown"…}
```

I get the object I want here. But when I make it a conditional

```
terah.spouse.spouse === terah;
>false
```

I get false... Why is this? It seems to be pointing to the same object. Even when I call

```
terah.spouse.spouse.name === "Terah"
>true
```

I get true there. Why do I get false with the object conditional? Thanks.`

Comment: The way your objects are set up, `adam.spouse` will be `undefined`. I assume this is not your actual code. As such, you should provide actual code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: How can you define `adam .. {spouse: terah}` before terah is defined? or how will you define `terah {spouse: adam}` before adam is defined? this gives me a headache...

Comment: In your example, `terah.spouse.spouse` *will* result `undefined`

Comment: @Darren When I try `terah.spouse.spouse.name === "Terah"` all I get is `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'terah.spouse.spouse.name')`

Comment: @Darren: I'm not sure why you've decided to provide code that doesn't do what you claim, but if `terah.spouse.spouse` doesn't equal `terah`, then that means it points to a different object than `terah`. If you it has the same properties, then you've created two `terah` objects, or created one that inherits from the original `terah`.

Comment: Yeah idk oGeez I always get something with terah.spouse.spouse every time. But you guys answered my question thanks.

Comment: ohhh i see cookie monster. thanks

Comment: Im just testing it in my console and mustve created a bunch of terah and adam objects so it was pointing to something but not the same one.

Comment: @DarrenDahl: If the object is logged early, but the property is populated later, then when you eventually read what's in the console, it'll show the updates to the object.

Comment: @DarrenDahl It's usually a good idea to doublecheck your code samples in a clean tab before posting ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to actually make that work is:

```
var adam = {
  name: "Adam"
};

var terah = {
  name: "Terah",
  age: 32,
  height: 66,
  weight: 125,
  hairColor: "brown"
};

adam.spouse = terah;
terah.spouse = adam;
```

It's not an *error* to reference the variable "terah" in the object literal initializing "adam" (thanks to the hoisting of `var` declarations), but at the point the code is evaluated the value of "terah" will be `undefined`. The fact that it's later given a value doesn't matter.

(The object literal for "terah" could refer to the "spouse" property of "adam", but I split that out for clarity.)

Note that a circular reference like this won't be serializable as JSON. It might not throw an exception, but there's no way to represent a cycle like that in JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Object view and make sure they're actually the same... running your code (a few times... because of the weird recursion) gives me

```
>terah.spouse.spouse
age: 32
hairColor: "brown"
height: 66
name: "Terah"
spouse: Object
name: "Adam"
spouse: undefined //undefined
__proto__: Object
weight: 125
__proto__: Object
>terah
age: 32
hairColor: "brown"
height: 66
name: "Terah"
spouse: Object
name: "Adam"
spouse: Object //not undefined! so they ARE different!
__proto__: Object
weight: 125
__proto__: Object
```

See? two object were created. the real `terah` and an earlier 'version' of `terah`.

Have you tried just setting `adam.spouse = terah`?

Answer (score 1):

At the time that you define `adam`, the object for `terah` doesn't exist, so at that time, `terah.spouse` is undefined. If you were to define Adam's spouse after defining Terah, you would get the result you are looking for:

```
var adam = {
    name: "Adam",
}

var terah = {
    name: "Terah",
    age: 32,
    height: 66,
    weight: 125,
    hairColor: "brown",
    spouse: adam
}

adam.spouse = terah

console.log(terah.spouse.spouse === terah) //true
```

Comment: That doesn't explain the output in the rest of the question. Clearly `adam.spouse` is not `undefined`.

Comment: In the original question, `adam.spouse` is set to an undefined variable (terah) so it *is* undefined. I'm not sure how the OP got the first output. [See here, undefined](http://jsfiddle.net/cfyf7/1/)

Comment: Right, that's my point. Since OP is getting an object at `adam.spouse`, then there's something additional that's missing in the question. Otherwise it wouldn't log an object, and `terah.spouse.spouse.name` would throw an error.

Comment: OK, but 'something missing in the question' is surely down to the OP? I've just answered the question how I can best, trying to interpret what the OP is asking.